# What is the best practise to do partitoning data in Azure Redis

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache, azure-caching, redis-cache

I am planning to use Redis cache in my application and the data size may vary from 10KB - 500 MB.
If I use the large key/value entries from Redis, Reding and Saving data might get performance issue, it means I have to transfer more data over the network from the server to the client and I might get below consequences.

1. It takes more time to transfer the data, so the client may need to have
   a higher timeout value configured to allow for this additional transfer time.
2. Requests made to the server can get stuck behind the big transfer and cause other requests to timeout.
3. Network buffers used to transfer this data can impact available memory on the client or server, which can aggravate the available memory issues described around fragmentation.
4. If these large key/value items are accessed frequently, this magnifies the impacts if we repeatedly transferring this data over and over again.

So I would like to do partitioning in Redis cache.

Example:
    I have an endpoint(GetEmployees(Some computation happens to get all employees)) which returns around 500 records with size 400 MB ( Example). I get the same data until I add any new employee so I want to have cache mechanism so that I can store these records and get it from the cache instead of doing calculations again and again.

If I store all records in the single shard of Redis, will face above mentioned issues.

Key/Value : GetEmplyeesTodayDate/ {List Of Records}

So, I would like to split the data and across shards and get all records when reading from Redis.

What is the best way to store all 500 records in Redis with same/multiple keys (s) and retrieve them?

Comment: you could refer any of the three mechanism for partitioning as per your feasibility Server Side partitioning, Client Side partitioning or proxy assited partitioning. you can refer this document for further details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#partitioning-a-redis-cache

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Anurag, you would use [Partitioning a Redis cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#partitioning-a-redis-cache) but when partitioning is used in conjuction with [Azure Redis Cache clustering](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-redis-cache-improve-performance-using-clustering/), you ensure that there will be no throughput issues with the cache itself: [How to configure Redis clustering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-clustering)

Same questions was asked in [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6498109f-320f-45c3-9afb-5840d5dab95c/what-is-the-best-practise-to-do-partitoning-data-in-azure-redis?forum=azurecache).